# adding images to a tab label

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I was looking to make tabs that look like the following:

[How do you add an image to TabControl's label in Winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019888/how-do-you-add-a-image-to-a-tab-label)

but in wpf C#.

I dynamically add the tabs and was hoping to change the image depending on if the tab had been saved or not (i already have the code for that part).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are looking for is the TabItems HeaderTemplate ...

XAML:

```
<TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="10" Height="10" Margin="3,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
```

instead of a rectangle you could specify an image or whatever element you want ...