# My tabControl1 wont show its DrawImage after I added custom backcolor to my tabControl1

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am not really sure where I am going wrong but before I added my custom backcolor to my tabControl1 everything worked fine, I saw the X on other tabs and the + to add tabs

[image]

After I added this source of code my Tabs I add are not there but the + button functions and going on other tabs functions aswell making me think that the backColor is just hiding them behind.

```
            SolidBrush backColor = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(40, 40, 40)); // change back color
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColor, rec);
```

[image]

Is there like any way that the Tab Pages display fully with the DrawItems I have put in with the backColor?

The code source:

```
        private void tabControl1_DrawItem_1(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle rec = tabControl1.ClientRectangle;

            SolidBrush backColor = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(40, 40, 40)); // change back color
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColor, rec);

            StringFormat StrFormat = new StringFormat();
            StrFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            StrFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

            Brush bshBack = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(55, 55, 55)); // change tab color

            var tabPage = this.tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index];
            var tabRect = this.tabControl1.GetTabRect(e.Index);
            tabRect.Inflate(-2, -2);
            if (e.Index == this.tabControl1.TabCount - 1)
            {
                // Add
                var addImage = Properties.Resources.Add;
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(bshBack, e.Bounds);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(addImage,
                    tabRect.Left + (tabRect.Width - addImage.Width) / 2,
                    tabRect.Top + (tabRect.Height - addImage.Height) / 2);
            }
            else
            {
                // Close
                var closeImage = Properties.Resources.Close;
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(bshBack, e.Bounds);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(closeImage,
                    (tabRect.Right - closeImage.Width),
                    tabRect.Top + (tabRect.Height - closeImage.Height) / 2);
                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, tabPage.Text, tabPage.Font,
                    tabRect, tabPage.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.Left);
            }
        }
```

Comment: [Workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822748/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-unused-space-tab-in-c-sharp-winforms).

Comment: yes it does work but whenever one of my tab pages is selected it makes this like white outline any way I could disable that? @dr.null

Comment: You won't get a nice result through `TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed`. For a better outcome, you need to takeover and paint the whole thing yourself. You can find many [examples](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91387/Painting-Your-Own-Tabs-Second-Edition-2) to do so. I'll try to find something close.

Comment: Yea if you could find something close to this https://prnt.sc/Vw13tXrb-KfG that would be great. ik its like a ton of work put into them custom ones but im trying my best to find everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend the [TabControl with Close and Add Button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36900582/14171304) solution. Create a new class and inherit from the `TabControl`, set the control styles shown below in the constructor to mainly draw the control and the tabs the way you want it.

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace YourProjectNamespace
{
    [DesignerCategory("Code")]
    [ToolboxBitmap(typeof(TabControl))]
    public class TabControlEx : TabControl
    {
        public TabControlEx() : base()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint
                | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw
                | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer
                | ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
            UpdateStyles();
            Padding = new Point(14, 4);
        }

        private Color backColor = Color.FromArgb(40, 40, 40);
        /// <inheritdoc cref="Control.BackColor"/>
        [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "40, 40, 40"),
            Browsable(true),
            EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),
            DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
        public new Color BackColor
        {
            get => backColor;
            set
            {
                if (backColor != value)
                {
                    backColor = value;
                    Invalidate();
                }
            }
        }

        private Image addImage;
        [DefaultValue(null)]
        public Image AddButtonImage
        {
            get => addImage;
            set
            {
                addImage = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        private Image closeImage;
        [DefaultValue(null)]
        public Image CloseButtonImage
        {
            get => closeImage;
            set
            {
                closeImage = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnHandleCreated(e);
            SendMessage(Handle, TCM_SETMINTABWIDTH, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)16);
            if (TabCount > 0) TabPages[TabCount - 1].Text = "";
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            var g = e.Graphics;

            g.Clear(BackColor);

            if (TabCount == 0) return;

            for (int i = 0; i < TabCount; i++)
            {
                var tp = TabPages[i];
                var r = Rectangle.Inflate(GetTabRect(i), -4, 0);

                if (i == TabCount - 1)
                {
                    if (AddButtonImage != null)
                        g.DrawImage(AddButtonImage,
                            r.X + (r.Width - AddButtonImage.Width) / 2,
                            r.Y + (r.Height - AddButtonImage.Height) / 2,
                            AddButtonImage.Width, AddButtonImage.Height);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (i == SelectedIndex)
                        using (var brSel = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(105, 105, 105)))
                            g.FillRectangle(brSel, Rectangle.Inflate(r, 4, 1));

                    if (ImageList != null && tp.ImageIndex >= 0)
                        ImageList.Draw(g, 
                            r.X, r.Y + (r.Height - ImageList.ImageSize.Height) / 2, 
                            tp.ImageIndex);

                    if (CloseButtonImage != null)
                    {
                        var closeRect = new Rectangle(new Point(
                            r.Right - CloseButtonImage.Width,
                            r.Y + (r.Height - CloseButtonImage.Height) / 2),
                            CloseButtonImage.Size);

                        g.DrawImage(CloseButtonImage, closeRect,
                            0, 0, CloseButtonImage.Width, CloseButtonImage.Height,
                            GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    }

                    TextRenderer.DrawText(g, tp.Text, tp.Font, r, Color.White,
                        TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | 
                        TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseUp(e);

            var lastIndex = TabCount - 1;
            if (GetTabRect(lastIndex).Contains(e.Location))
            {
                var args = new AddingTabEventArgs();
                OnAddingTab(args);
                if (args.Cancel) return;

                var newTp = new TabPage
                {
                    Text = "New Tab",
                    BackColor = BackColor
                };
                TabPages.Insert(lastIndex, newTp);
                SelectedIndex = lastIndex;
            }
            else
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < TabPages.Count; i++)
                {
                    var r = Rectangle.Inflate(GetTabRect(i), -4, 0);

                    if (new Rectangle(r.Right - 16, r.Y + (r.Height - 16), 16, 16)
                        .Contains(e.Location))
                    {
                        var args = new ClosingTabEventArgs(TabPages[i]);
                        OnClosingTab(args);
                        if (args.Cancel) return;

                        TabPages[i].Dispose();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnSelecting(TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.TabPageIndex == TabCount - 1)
                e.Cancel = true;
            else
                base.OnSelecting(e);
        }

        public event EventHandler<ClosingTabEventArgs> ClosingTab;

        protected virtual void OnClosingTab(ClosingTabEventArgs e) => 
            ClosingTab?.Invoke(this, e);

        public event EventHandler<AddingTabEventArgs> AddingTab;

        protected virtual void OnAddingTab(AddingTabEventArgs e) =>
            AddingTab?.Invoke(this, e);

        const int TCM_SETMINTABWIDTH = 0x1300 + 49;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
    }

    public class ClosingTabEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public ClosingTabEventArgs(TabPage tp) => TabPage = tp;

        public TabPage TabPage { get; }

        public bool Cancel { get; set; }
    }

    public class AddingTabEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public AddingTabEventArgs() { }

        public bool Cancel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Note, I've added two more events, `AddingTab` and `ClosingTab` to trap them in your implementation and do whatever you need, including cancelation.

```cs
private void tabControlEx1_AddingTab(object sender, AddingTabEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Add new TabPage?", "Alert", 
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
        e.Cancel = true;
}

private void tabControlEx1_ClosingTab(object sender, ClosingTabEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show($"Remove {e.TabPage.Text}?", "Alert", 
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Of course, you can extend the control more and add more drawing properties like the back/foreground colors of the normal and selected tabs. Also, you can try the [`LinearGradientBrush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.lineargradientbrush?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) to fill the backgrounds instead of the solid brushes.

Rebuild, on the top of the `ToolBox` window, find and drop an instance. Try and go back to the code to add your touch.

[image: SOQ72179300]

Comment: if i may ask how do i use it? like how do i call it

Comment: i pasted the code in and this is what i got: https://prnt.sc/g5H0CYwStNwN

Comment: @VWWE See the edit. You need to replace the old TabControl with this one. Either,  drop a new instance into the designer **or** edit the `Form.Designer.cs` to change the type of the existing `TabControl` to `TabControlEx` or whatever you name this custom control.

Comment: Thanks for the help but like this is just confusign me too much when I paste in the code the other code I use for like Draw and MouseDown underlines tabControl1 and I'm just beyond confused but I'll just keep trying with the code you sent me and I hope I get somewhere with it, since I'm not gonna bother you much

Comment: Could you send a Visual Studio Project, if you can @dr.null

Comment: Not bothering, you're welcome. Just follow these steps: 1) Forget your old `TabControl`. 2) Select your project. 3) Press `Shift+Alt+C` keys to open the add item dialog. 3) Rename the class to `TabControlEx` and hit Add. 4) In the new class and within the namespace, replace the `class TabControlEx { }` part with the code above. 5) Rebuild. 6) Open a Form in your project. 7) From the top of the `ToolBox` window, find `TabControlEx` and drop an instance in the designer. That's all.

Comment: Yea alright I got to the point where I can put in my TabControlEx and now how do I add the images and whenever I press close or add it says "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'" line 175 for close and 180 for add @dr.null

Comment: Right, you found a bug. Forgot a `null` check in the events invokers. Just append `?` to the events. `ClosingTab?.Invoke(this, e);` and `AddingTab?.Invoke(this, e);`. As for the images, if you mean the Add and Close images. then select the control and press `F4` to activate the Properties window, Find the `AddButtonImage` and `CloseButtonImage` to set them. Click the ` . ` button and select an image for each from the select resource dialog. If you mean the other images on the left, then you need to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4019948/14171304) answer.

Comment: Alright thanks you so much for the help appreciate it. Also if I was to add like a WebBrowser everytime I add a tab would I put it in the TabControlEx.cs or the `tabControlEx1_AddingTab`?

Comment: Never mind found out how, thanks again.

Comment: The anchor doesn't seem to be working when I resize on the TabControlEx? @dr.null

Comment: @VWWE Anchor of which? Make sure you select the right control before you set the Anchor property. Just checked again and everything works as it should.

Comment: Ah it works now probably put the anchor on my tabpage or something. Thanks again