# C# winforms tabcontrol remove background of the header

Tags: c#, winforms

The issue is that I want to modify the tab control header background, but I can't achieve this. :/

[image]

On the screen, you can see the default control color of the tab control... this is frustrating!

Im using this code to remove the useless bottom, left and right border + redraw the text in the header, this works without problem, but i cant remove the useless TOP default control color of the header background (yellow marked on the screen)...

```
            `tabControl1.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;

            tabControl1.DrawItem += (sender, e) =>
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.DarkGray, e.Bounds);

                Color textColor = Color.White;

                if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
                {
                    textColor = Color.Red;
                }

                TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font,
                    e.Bounds, textColor, TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter);
            };

            this.NativeTabControl1 = new NativeTabControl();
            this.NativeTabControl1.AssignHandle(this.tabControl1.Handle);


    private NativeTabControl NativeTabControl1;
    private class NativeTabControl : NativeWindow
    {
        protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
        {
            if ((m.Msg == TCM_ADJUSTRECT))
            {
                RECT rc = (RECT)m.GetLParam(typeof(RECT));
                //Adjust these values to suit, dependant upon Appearance
                rc.Left -= 5;
                rc.Right += 3;
                rc.Top -= 3;
                rc.Bottom += 3;
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(rc, m.LParam, true);
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }

        private const Int32 TCM_FIRST = 0x1300;
        private const Int32 TCM_ADJUSTRECT = (TCM_FIRST + 40);
        private struct RECT
        {
            public Int32 Left;
            public Int32 Top;
            public Int32 Right;
            public Int32 Bottom;
        }
    }`
```

Thanks!

Edit: Yes i tryed too it with the Appearance, but this too not working..

Edit 2: Or is this the full standard tabcontrol background? if yes, how to remove this?

Comment: Fundamental about Winforms, its controls are painted with user-selected theme colors.  So that every tabcontrol looks the same, no matter what program uses it, helping the user to instantly know how to use it.  If heavy customization of the look-and-feel of your program is the goal, Winforms shouldn't be your preferred choice.

Comment: You should build a Custom Control instead of using a NativeWindow. [DrawThemeParentBackground](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-drawthemeparentbackground) can be used to draw the Parent's background onto the Control's DC. Overriding `OnPaintBackground()` makes it easier (instead of handling messages, I mean)

Comment: That region is transparent, put the `TabControl` in a `Panel` and change the panel `BackColor` to some color. See whether that is what you need before digging any deeper. Or create your own custom TC. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72179300/14171304).